# upgrading node version from 14.x.x to 16.x.x

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

While upgrading from node version 14.x.x to 16.x.x I see a different behavior when it comes to warnings. when I do npm install I noticed that a note in 14.x.x are showing up as failures in 16.x.x,

For example here is the 14.x.x warning
`npm WARN icss-utils@5.1.0 requires a peer of postcss@^8.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

While with 16.x.x I see

```
npm WARN While resolving: icss-utils@5.1.0
npm WARN Found: postcss@6.0.23                       
npm WARN node_modules/postcss
npm WARN   dev postcss@"~6.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   10 more (autoprefixer, postcss-html, postcss-loader, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer postcss@"^8.1.0" from icss-utils@5.1.0.  
npm WARN node_modules/icss-utils
npm WARN   icss-utils@"^5.1.0" from css-loader@6.7.2   
npm WARN   node_modules/css-loader
npm WARN   2 more (postcss-modules-local-by-default, postcss-modules-values)
```

It says warning but installation fails.

Moreover the application comes up just fine in 14.x.x in spite of the warning.

Why is that the case?

Comment: Can you try to run `npm i -D postcss@^8.1.0`